# ES6: Why Symbol can not have another symbol as description?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, symbols

I am learning Es6: [Symbols](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/). I am playing with it and trying to create a symbol using another symbol as description:

```
var s = Symbol('foo');
console.log(s.toString()); //"Symbol(foo)"
var sS = Symbol(s); // <- thorws error
var sF = Symbol.for(s); // <- thorws error
console.log(s, sA);
```

I am not able to understand **why is it not letting me use existing symbol as description**. When I run the code above I see following console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
    at Function.for (native)
```

As the error says that it can not convert the symbol to string. But as you see in code(line 2), by using `toString()` function I am able to convert the symbol in string. Can anyone please elaborate what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: `s` is already a `Symbol`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why is it not letting me use existing symbol as description

Simply because all descriptions must be strings, nothing else.

> the error says that it can not convert the symbol to string, but by using `toString()` I am able to convert the symbol in string

Yes, you can *explicitly* cast a symbol to a string and get its description by using the `toString` method. But all implicit conversions throw exceptions - this is a [deliberate feature](http://www.2ality.com/2014/12/es6-symbols.html#safety_checks) to prevent us from accidentally using the non-unique description instead of the symbol, e.g. when doing string concatenation with a property key.

Comment: A bit more in detail, the [argument of `String()` will have the internal function `ToString` applied to it](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-symbol-description). If it is almost anything other than a symbol, it will be fine - the description will be the textual representation of that - so `Symbol(1)`, `Symbol({a:"b"})` and `Symbol(undefined)` all work. However, `ToString()` is [defined to throw exception](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring) when given a symbol. `Symbol.prototype.toString` working, but internal `ToString` not is not a contradiction.